# How to get the response body after RestClientException is thrown after a 401 Error

Tags: java, spring, rest

I'm making a call to a Magento REST service which returns a message if there was an error.  For a 401 error the response body should be `{"message":"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."}`).  Using RestTemplate how do I get to the body?

```
public GetTokenResponse call(String url, GetTokenRequest request)
{
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    try {
        ResponseEntity<GetTokenResponse> result = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, GetTokenResponse.class);
        // throws RestClientException on 401 error
        return result.getBody();
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
        // responseBody shows empty
        throw new UnrecoverableException(e);
    }
}
```

I know that there is a response body present in the payload coming back from the server.  Here is the response body I pulled from WireShark:
[image]

**Edit:** When I call a method that gets a 400 error the body is populated correctly so this appears to be limited to certain statuses?

Comment: Note that the exception in the linked duplicate also exposes the response body.

Comment: There is a method to get the response body but it is just an empty byte array.

Comment: Then I'm doubtful of the body in the response. Looking at the source code of `RestTemplate`, it only ever creates a `HttpClientErrorException` with the constructor that accepts a body argument. Try to use `RestTemplate#setErrorHandler` with a custom `ResponseErrorHandler` and see what's available there.

Comment: I can curl the endpoint and see the response body.  That's where `{"message":"You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled."}` came from.

Comment: What version of the library are you using?

Comment: I've tried 3.1.1 and 4.3.1

Comment: `HttpClientErrorException#getResponseBodyAsByteArray` works fine for me. Is the URL you're testing public?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118650/discussion-between-brian-harman-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Comment: The issue isn't really Spring. It's `HttpURLConnection` which `RestTemplate` uses by default. It's set up to use some kind of streaming mode which your web server rejects.

Comment: Use a different HTTP client like Apache's Http Components with `restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory());` (or Netty, or OkHttp, or whatever other HTTP library) and you'll get the body you expected.

Comment: Check the duplicated question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54986825/3957754